# how to detect japanese word using google vision with horizontal line or using TEXT_DETECTION to Detect text in files (PDF)

Tags: python, ocr, cjk, google-vision

I using google vision to detect document text with PDF file but i have some trouble width result of response.

1. result of response is great but some symbols detect with vertical line. I know japan using vertical for writing but i don't need that. how can i add condition for this.

example

[a,b,c]

[x,y,z]

[1,2,3]

expected results: [a,b,c],[x,y,z],[1,2,3] or [a],[b],[c],[x],[y],[z],[1],[2],[3]

actual results: [a,b][x,y][1,2][c,z,3]

2. if 1 is impossible. Can i change type of feature is TEXT_DETECTION ?.
3. bounding_box have 4 point

{"x": 0.5579832,"y": 0.912114},

{"x": 0.5579832,"y": 0.91567695},

{"x": 0.53781515, "y": 0.91567695},

{"x": 0.53781515,"y": 0.912114}

and pages have width and height but some x ,y have a value > 1.0 it will Page limit exceeded how can i convert to width and height with the point

thanks you ^^

reference: 
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf 
and change only image_context={"language_hints": ["ja"]}

https://medium.com/weareservian/my-tips-for-getting-help-with-google-cloud-platform-114b03f807dc

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Please convert to PDF file, i want detect with 2 function image and pdf. image is ok because i using TEXT_DETECTION  but with PDF i cant do it

Comment: 1. Google vision will sometimes predict character's position which is cropped at the edge of the image so their coordinate may be either smaller than 0 or larger than width/height, you will need to use `max` and `min` function to resolve this.

Comment: 2. Google API only work with image so i suggest you convert PDF to image first, one solution for this is the `pdf2image` module (https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image)

Comment: 3. The coordinates you receive from your example are weird because the text's position is random (not all vertical but also not all horizontal). In this case I think you will need to extract each character's position (yes, they do return it) and then build your own algorithm to sort them.

Comment: Thank for support to me, i will do it. google support Detect text in files (PDF), it want i upload image to GCS and make so much step but result is not my hope. i want google update some feature to improve Detect text in files (PDF) in future

Answer (score 0):

I might be late, but the 1st option is definitely possible. From what I understand, you need to detect the language horizontally. For that, what you can do is, get all the bounding boxes, calculate their center, then align them according to the center point location.

First, create a dictionary that will contain all the detected words or characters and their respective bounds (x1,x2,x3,x4 and y1,y2,y3,y4). Using those bounds, calculate the center points.

Following is the example for doing so:

```
    for bound in bounds:
      y1 = bound.normalized_vertices[0].y * pdf_height
      y2 = bound.normalized_vertices[1].y * pdf_height
      y3 = bound.normalized_vertices[2].y * pdf_height
      y4 = bound.normalized_vertices[3].y * pdf_height

      x1 = bound.normalized_vertices[0].x * pdf_width
      x2 = bound.normalized_vertices[1].x * pdf_width
      x3 = bound.normalized_vertices[2].x * pdf_width
      x4 = bound.normalized_vertices[3].x * pdf_width

      y_center = (y1+y2+y3+y4)/4
      x_center = (x1+x2+x3+x4)/4
```

After getting all the vertices, put them in a list, and update the bounds present in the dictionary. Now, the dictionary will contain words and their respective x_center, and y_center. After getting these points, sort them according to your needs.

For me, I first sorted them according to the y-axis in ascending order. Doing so, I was able to sort the words coming in same line, and then separated the lines using a line break.

For getting the correct sequence of the words, just sort them according to the x-axis.

Please bear one thing in the mind, you would need to set a tolerance value for getting the correct words in same line, otherwise, two lines can get mixed up with one another. Also, the tolerance value will also depend on font size.

This is the main logic behind the horizontal text detection using Google vision. I can't share the rest of the code as it is my company's property. So, sorry for that in advance. Just letting you all know that it is certainly possible. :)